# PHP: Accessing class attributes from inherited classes

Tags: php, object

I am trying to create class attributes in the constructor, and then access them in an extended class, but am having trouble getting at them.

Here is my setup, apologies, lots of code.

```
class Object {
    function __autoload($c){
        strtolower($c);
        include_once('lib/'.$c);
    }

    function  __construct() {

    }
}

class Rules extends Object{

    function __autoload(){
        include_once('lib/rules.php');
    }

    // Store our set of rules
    public static $consonant = '';
    public static $vowel = '';
    public static $other = '';

    function  __construct() {
        global $_CONF;

        // Store a set of rules, as we create them from the config
        $this->consonant = '/^[^'.$_CONF['vowels'].$_CONF['additional'].']+/';
        $this->vowel = '/['.$_CONF['vowels'].']+/';
        $this->other = '/^('.$_CONF['additional'].'+)(.*)/';
    }
}
```

Here is where I'm having trouble

```
class Translate extends Rules{

    function __autoload(){
        include_once('lib/translate.php');
    }

    function  __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    // etc, function()
    $return .= preg_replace(parent::$vowel, "$1$2'".$_CONF['vowelending'], $word);
}
```

> Warning: preg_replace()
>   [function.preg-replace]: Empty regular
>   expression in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\PigLatin2\lib\translate.php
>   on line 45

Now to me this is obvious that the parent class attribute is not being read correctly. I have changed it from `parent::vowel` to `parent::$vowel` and made them `static`, but it's still not reading the correct value.

Do I need to instantiate a new copy of `$rule = new Rules()` in my constructor? Or should Translate auto load, as it's extending the parent?

Comment: This is wrong on so many levels. Please get rid of the Base Object, empty ctors, false inheritance, superfluous __autoloads, globals and statics. Your not doing OOP, you're doing class based programming.

Comment: You never assign the result of `strtolower($c)` to anything. Perhaps you meant `$c = strtolower($c);`

Comment: @Gordon Please can you recommend a good place for me to start?

Comment: try this [Wikipedia article about SOLID](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29) and then follow the links. OOP is easy to start with, but hard to get right, even after years of learning, so no worries :) Also, see if there is any PHP Usergroups in your area to discuss topics like that.

Comment: @Gordon Thanks! I'll have a read and redevelop my application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Translate` class, `parent::$vowel` would refer to a static attribute, in the `Rules` class.

Your properties are not `static`, so you shoud instead use `$this->vowel`.